# Java Pattern single line mode

Tags: java, regex, user-input

I am trying to read a multiline console input from a user with a custom end of line char sequence. For this I am using the java.util.Scanner class with a custom regex to define the desired input.

But the Scanner always matches the last line and ignores previous lines that include line terminating symbols. On a online regex testing website, I found out that I had to use single line mode in order to include line terminating symbols.

So I modified my regex to include "(?s)", which works fine on the online regex tester but fails in my code. Here a minimal working example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input that ends with the number 4:");
        input.findWithinHorizon(".*4",0);
        System.out.println("Input that ends with the number 4 and uses single line mode:");
        input.findWithinHorizon("(?s).*4",0);
    }
}
```

The first regex terminates after entering the number 4, but the second one seems to never terminate. Somehow the "?s"-flag seems to break it. Any ideas?

Comment: What is ?s supposed to match?

Comment: As I wrote it in the text, it enables a flag so the dot symbol in the regex also matches terminating symbols. On regex101.com it states the following about that flag: "s modifier: single line. Dot matches newline characters"